# EDIT: SOLVED: How do I get decrypter to ignore whitespace but still output with whitespace?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement, whitespace

I am trying to make a vignette decoder. I have figured out how make it work, but am unable to put spaces. It simply just stops the program. I can't just tell it to not see it since the letters all have to be counted and matched to a specific letter. So in other words, "wml kmna" decodes as "hey guys". But the key is PINES. So I need to to line up like P=w I=m  N=l E=k S=m P=n I=a.
I got it to work and it decodes it perfectly, but when I try to add space, it just stops at the first word and doesn't keep going. Without the space, it works fine. Here is my code. I know I have some unneeded imports, I was trying different things and those were pulled in.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.lang.*;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] arrayOfLetters = new String[12];
String letters;
int x = 10;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter 12 Letters:");
letters = sc.next();
arrayOfLetters = letters.split("");

for(int a = 0; a < arrayOfLetters.length; a++){
    char b = letters.charAt(a);
    if(a % 10 == 0 || a % 10 ==  5){
        int p = b + 11;
        if(p > 122){
            int f = (p - 122) +96;
            System.out.print((char)f);
        }
        else
        System.out.print((char)p);
    }
        
    if(a % 10 == 1 || a % 10 ==6 ){
        int i = b + 18;
        if(i > 122){
            int f = (i - 122) +96;
            System.out.print((char)f);
        }
        else
        System.out.print((char)i);
    }

    if(a % 10 == 2 || a % 10 == 7){
        int n = b + 13;
        if(n > 122){
            int f = (n - 122) +96;
            System.out.print((char)f);
        }
        else
        System.out.print((char)n);
    }

    if(a % 10 == 3 || a % 10 == 8){
        int e = b + 22;
         if(e > 122){
            int f = (e - 122) +96;
            System.out.print((char)f);
        }
        else
        System.out.print((char)e);
    }


    if(a % 10 == 4 || a % 10 == 9){
        int s = b + 8;
        if(s > 122){
            int f = (s - 122) +96;
            System.out.print((char)f);
        }
        else
        System.out.print((char)s);
    }
}
```

I figured it out! I had the array store the words instead of the letters. I then did multiple loops to go through and get the word and then process each letter of that word and enter a space if the word is complete. Here is the code for anyone struggling! I also added a word count at the end so you know where you left off. Since it has to be divisible by 5.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[]args){
String[] arrayOfLetters = new String[100];
String letters;

Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print ("Enter Sentence to be Decoded:");
  letters = sc.nextLine();
  arrayOfLetters = letters.split(" ");
  int co = 0;
  
   for(int a = 0; a < arrayOfLetters.length; a++){
       if(a > 0){
           System.out.print(" ");
       }
    for(int c = 0; c < arrayOfLetters[a].length(); c++){
        char b = arrayOfLetters[a].charAt(c);
            
            if (co % 10 == 0 || co % 10 == 5){
                int p = b + 11;
                if (p > 122){
                    int f = (p - 122) + 96;
                    System.out.print ((char) f);
                }
            else
                System.out.print ((char) p);
            }
        
            if (co % 10 == 1 || co % 10 == 6){
                int i = b + 18;
                if (i > 122){
                    int f = (i - 122) + 96;
                    System.out.print ((char) f);
                }
            else
                System.out.print ((char) i);
            }
        
            if (co % 10 == 2 || co % 10 == 7){
                int n = b + 13;
                if (n > 122){
                    int f = (n - 122) + 96;
                    System.out.print ((char) f);
                }
            else
               System.out.print ((char) n);
            }
        
            if (co % 10 == 3 || co % 10 == 8){
                int e = b + 22;
                if (e > 122){
                    int f = (e - 122) + 96;
                    System.out.print ((char) f);
                }
            else
                System.out.print ((char) e);
            }
        
            if (co % 10 == 4 || co % 10 == 9){
                int s = b + 8;
                if (s > 122){
                    int f = (s - 122) + 96;
                    System.out.print ((char) f);
            }
            else
                System.out.print ((char) s);
            }
            co++;

        }
        sc.close ();
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "Letter count: " + co);
  
}
```

Comment: You remove punctuation and spaces first. See [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher)

Comment: I actually tried that, but how to I insert the spaces again? I want it to output the sentence with the spaces between the words.

Comment: First thought is use `Matcher` on alpha alone. Start and end will show you what to act on. You can even leave all else where it is

Comment: I am a newbie and haven't heard of that. But I googled it and it seems like a good option! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. ```Matcher.find()```  could be used with pattern ```"\\p{Alpha}+"```. ```group(0)``` will show you where they start and end

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example of how it would be used in my code? Thanks

Comment: I also thought of if the ASCII is less than 97, add a space instead of a character. But then I still run into it not lining up with the keyword. So I thought maybe if I shifted the array back one so the next character fills the currrent space and then continue, it might work. I am trying
    if(b < 97){
        System.out.print(" ");
        arrayOfLetters[a] = arrayOfLetters[a + 1];
    }
But no luck.
I can't get it to show the code properly in the comment for some reason...